# Power Shell Advice (delete all folders/subfolders not matching a certain name)

Tags: powershell

How would I use powershell to delete all folders/subfolders not matching a certain name.

We have a bunch of files on our production server that never made it into our CMS and uploading everything with a matching file tree would be amazing but we just need the */pdf/* folders.

Comment: Do you have an example of the code that you've tried?

Comment: May we see your code attempt? You may want to look into `Get-ChildItem` and `Remove-Item`.

Comment: At the very least, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68670291/edit) and provide **your** code attempt, a description of what went wrong and examples of the folder tree would help a lot.